# Minitest::Mock and case statements

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest

Any idea why the following code does not work?

```
require 'minitest/mock'

test = Minitest::Mock.new
test.expect :class, Class

p case test
when Class
  'class'
else
  'nope'
end # => 'nope' … but should return 'class'

p test.class === Class # => true
```

Comment: shouldn't it be ``case text.class``?

Comment: The Ruby `case` handles the `===` comparison without an explicit call to `class`, although making the explicit comparison on the result of `test.class` makes the above code work.

Comment: The problem is that the case statement is in a class I have no access to.

Comment: `case` doesn't use any explicit call to `class` to perform the comparison here, so your expectation is never evaluated.

This is the point where you need to ask yourself what you're hoping to achieve by mocking `class` on the object under test.  I'm not clear about what the above code is meant to demonstrate, but when your tests need to be this invasive, it's usually a smell.

Comment: So there is no way to get this working?

Comment: My guess is that Ruby's implementation of `case` is implemented in C, so `class` will probably never be called and the expectation never satisfied.

Comment: Ok good - well not good, but I can do a workaround. Thx for the help, and btw if you post your comments as an answer, I will accept it (for the reputation)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby `case` handles the `===` comparison without an explicit call to `class`, although making the explicit comparison on the result of `test.class` makes the above code work.

If you can't do that though, as you've said above, you may not be able to get a `case` like this to work.  My guess is that Ruby's implementation of `case` is implemented in C, so `class` will probably never be called and the expectation never satisfied.